# Parsing JSON into swift predefined array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to get items from an api (JSON) and to parse it into a predefined swift array. I have searched and looked for hours but due to my lack of skills I wasn't able to find anything suitable my case.

My predefined array looks like this:

```
init?(participants: String, photoguest: UIImage?, photohome: UIImage?, time: String, stadium: String, channel: String)
```

the JSON structure is like this([entire json file](http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/schedule/json/test/)):

```
{"gameId":"255","gameWeek":"17","gameDate":"2016-01-03","awayTeam":"SEA","homeTeam":"ARI","gameTimeET":"4:25 PM","tvStation":"FOX","winner":"SEA"}
```

My current code looks like this (Games is the class where I connect variables from array with table cell items):

```
var gameplan = [Games]()

func loadNFLgames(){

    let apiURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/schedule/json/test/")
    let data: AnyObject? = NSData(contentsOfURL: apiURL!)


    let homeTeam = (data as! NSDictionary)["homeTeam"] as! String
    let awayTeam = (data as! NSDictionary)["awayTeam"] as! String
    let gameDate = (data as! NSDictionary)["gameDate"] as! String
    let gameTimeET = (data as! NSDictionary)["gameTimeET"] as! String
    let tvStation = (data as! NSDictionary)["tvStation"] as! String

    /*
    for schleife mit API daten:
        for gameWeek = currentWeek{ //every game where gameWeek matches currentWeek
    */

    // create variables from api calls
    let api_guest = awayTeam
    let api_home = homeTeam
    let api_tvhost = tvStation
    let api_time = gameDate + ", " + gameTimeET + " ET" // convert gameDate to day e.g. SUN
    let api_stadion = "N/A"

    // prepare data for array
    let gamedata = Games(participants: api_guest+" @ "+api_home, photoguest: UIImage(named: api_guest), photohome: UIImage(named: api_home), time: api_time, stadium: api_stadion, channel: api_tvhost)!

    // add data to array
    gameplan.append(gamedata)
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '_NSInlineData' (0x1a0cfd428) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x1a0cf3380).

EDIT: The error is being thrown here:

```
let homeTeam = (data as! NSDictionary)["homeTeam"] as! String
```

Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Um .. Whats the question

Comment: sorry updated the post

Comment: And which line is throwing the error, or we suppose to guess?

Comment: NSDictionary error is throwing in the line:
`let homeTeam = (data as! NSDictionary)["homeTeam"] as! String`

Comment: U need to parse the schedule array, then you loop for each nsdictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello your data variable doesn't contain the Json you r looking for. so you have to serialize it to json like alexander suggested but NSJSONSerialization can throw an error so we have tu put in in `try`
so your code will be something like this (i suggest always using dispatch_async to make it in background thread than use the completion closure to get your result)-->

```
    func loadNFLgames(completionClosure: (result : [Games]) ->()){
        let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        dispatch_async(queue, {
            let URL = "http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/schedule/json/test/"
            print(URL)
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: URL)!){
                if let JsonObject = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary{
                    print(JsonObject)
                    //here you can loop through the JsonObject to get the data you are looking for
                    //when you get your array of Games just pass it the the completion closure like this
completionClosure(result: gameplan)
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

**PS: please let me know if you need more help.**

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work without an error but I get a warning: `Cast from 'NSData' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails`. The cells are not being displayed in the end but at least the table loads. Do you know a fix for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: nevermind I fixed it :) . Sorry I just started developing with swift.

Comment: its ok . im glad it helped

Comment: I am still having problems with displaying the cells but at least I don't run into errors anymore.

Comment: could you paste your code ? it would be helpful. dont forget to call tableView.reloadData() in the completion closure.

Comment: I got it working before I added the api parse, just to make sure to get it working. I posted the code here: https://pastebin.com/JeWk2vQ5

Comment: your calling the wrong function to load the data, 
you have to remove the linge 24 "func loadNFLgames(){" in your file and then instead of loadNFLgames() in line 21 you have to call the function like this -->

        loadNFLgames { (result) -> () in
            self.gameplan = result
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

Comment: OK this works, but the app crashes after loading the api, it parses the api as print and then spits out: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` seems like it spits it out when it goes to the variables :/

Comment: please consider adding a new question with your new code and specifying which line throws the error thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is NSData type (not NSDictionary). You have to convert it in order to use it. Try something like that:

`let decodedJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil) as! NSDictionary`

And than you can use it like standard dictionary

`let homeTeam = decodedJson["homeTeam"] as! String`

Comment: I can somehow not use `nil` nor can I use `0` as NSReadoptions

Comment: fixed it with `options: []` but getting another error on the NSJSONSerialization `call can throw but it is not marked with try `

Comment: try the following:

`do {
 let decodedJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil) as! NSDictionary
}
catch error {
// error handle
}`

Or, if you 100% sure, that transformation will be without any errors you can do it in the following way

' let decodedJson = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil) as! NSDictionary'